# How to leave a copy of the original file when we save the file

Tags: c#, .net

When modifying and saving a file, how to leave a copy of the original file, say give it *.bak?Is there a built-in support?

Comment: To answer the direct question: as far as I know there is no built-in support for such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the .NET framework to simply copy the file to a .bak and then modify the original.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `File.Move` to rename the original file, then save the new version with the original name.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example:

```
// This is the current file
string filePath = @"C:\temp\test.txt";

//Now change file extension to text.bak
string filePathBak = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "bak");

// Save orginal file
File.Move(filePath, filePathBak);
```